# Rails validate model which receive values using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have 2 models: `Dealer` & `Location`.

```
class Dealer < AR::Base
  has_many :locations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations

  validate :should_has_one_default_location

  private

  def should_has_one_default_location
    if locations.where(default: true).count != 0
      errors.add(:base, "Should has exactly one default location")
    end
  end
end

class Location < AR::Base
  # boolean attribute :default
  belongs_to :dealer
end
```

As you understood, `should_has_one_location` adds error everytime, because `.where(default: true)` makes an sql query. How can I avoid this behaviour?

The very dirty solution is to use combination of `inverse_of` and `select` instead of where, but it seems very dirty. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey there, did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Hey! The best solution here in my opinion - to do something w/ your schema

Answer (score 0):

I actually got an answer to a similar question of my own.  For whatever it's worth, If you wanted to do a validation like you have above (but without the db query), you would do the following:

```
errors.add(:base, ""Should have exactly one default location") unless locations.any?{|location| location.default == 'true'}
```